# Is there something that crops or resizes the pdf page by its TrimBox?

Tags: printing, software-recommendation, pdf

I am developing an application that makes pdf files, but I am adding the trimbox values to the pdf pages with a different way, hence I need debug my pdf file to check trimbox values that I set with my way, working or not. But I don't have printer. Is there something that crops or resizes the pdf pages by their trimbox values, thus I can put my pdf file which is generated with my application to that app and being sure trimbox values that I set with my way works or not. Currently I have tried these applications:

Okular
qpdfview
Boomaga (as virtual printer)
CUPS-PDF (as virtual printer)

But I could not find any settings in okular and qpdfview to crop or resize the pdf pages by their trimbox values. I have printed my pdf file whose pages have trimbox values (with my way or ready pdf file that I know trimbox values properly added to the pages) as again pdf file in Boomaga and CUPS-PDF. But I could not see any change about page's dimensions or cropping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghostscript can be used to rewrite PDF files with the pages cropped to the *trim box*, by using the following option (from https://ghostscript.com/docs/9.54.0/Use.htm#PDF_switches):

> -dUseTrimBox
> Sets the page size to the TrimBox rather than the MediaBox. The trim box defines the intended dimensions of the finished page after
> trimming. Some files have a TrimBox that is smaller than the MediaBox
> and may include white space, registration or cutting marks outside the
> CropBox. Using this option simulates appearance of the finished
> printed page.

There are also options to use the other bounding boxes.

Use the command line:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dUseTrimBox -o $OUT.pdf $IN.pdf
```

It should already be installed, but if not can be with `sudo apt install ghostscript`.